# PHP accessing $_GET parameters

Tags: php, query-string

http://example.com/category/lorem?s=search+query

I am trying to get the last parameter i tried this one

```
print_r($_GET);
```

but it didnt print the last part result is

```
page = category | id = lorem
```

this one is for who says what is .htaccess your rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]*) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please add the output you got and the output you expected.

Comment: sorry i am fighting with stackoverflow so i will describe my problem from here. i am trying to access the last part in php you know ?s=search+query but when i print $_GET this only shows page = category and id = lorem. i need how can i access the last part

Comment: $_GET is an associative array

Comment: Is that supposed to be `lorem.php`? What did you get? It should give your an array with the key `s` and the value `search query`.

Comment: sorry im fighting with stackoverflow please look comment then i can edit the question

Comment: $_GET['something']

Comment: It might be related to the way the url is parsed (mod_rewrite rules likely).

Comment: Ah, I see that you seem to be using rewriting. Are you using `.htaccess` for that? What is the rule?

Comment: Post the entire .htaccess file here.

Comment: Do you want to get this parameter `s=search+query`?

Comment: yes sure i want this one value ?s=

Comment: think like that i am on example.com/category/lorem im submitted a form (form action is get) then url is example.com/category/lorem?s=search+query im trying to get ?s= value on this part

Comment: Assuming your URL gets affected by the first rule, you need to change the option to `[L,QSA]`, like the second one. the `QSA` allows the query string to go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created new page called search.php and im submitting form to this with get method now my url looks like search?s=search+query and now it looks good i can get the "s" with $_GET['s']